# Jsession in tomcat configuration

Tags: apache, tomcat, session-cookies

I have found that the value of my `jsessionid` cookies is `value.*tomcatid*` – e.g `jsessionid=ahvrbsbbdhdhwh.tc12`.

Where can I find the configuration of the Tomcat ID which is being concatenated with the `jsessionid` value?

Comment: You have configured a load balancer with sticky sessions. The suffix after the period '.' is required for routing to the correct Tomcat instance. Aspects of this can be configured in the [workers.properties](https://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/reference/workers.html).

Comment: I search for the file workers.properties but no result found , Can the value be written in another configuration file

Comment: It can have an arbitrary name. If you are using Apache httpd the name is specified the file name is specified [by the `JkWorkersFile` option](https://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/apache.html). But as you are not providing any hint about your setup it's all guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suffix you are seeing is called the `jvmRoute` and is configured in mod_jk's `workers.properties` file as either the *name* of the worker:

```
worker.tc12.type=AJP13
(etc)
```

or by explicitly setting the name of the `route` [property](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/reference/workers.html#Advanced_Worker_Directives):

```
worker.longname.type=AJP13
worker.longname.route=tc12
(etc)
```

In Tomcat, the `jvmRoute` is set in `conf/server.xml` on the `<Engine>` [element](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/engine.html#Common_Attributes):

```
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="tc12">
```

If you want to change the route names, you will need to adjust both your mod_jk and Tomcat configurations to match each other.

If you want to remove this suffix, then you will have to disable sticky sessions in mod_jk (sticky sessions are the default configuration) and also remove the `jvmRoute` attribute in your `conf/server.xml`:

```
workers.properties
------------------
worker.rc12.sticky_session = false
```

and:

```
conf/server.xml
---------------
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
```

This will disable sticky sessions which means that every request will go to an arbitrary Tomcat server.

Even if you do not *need* sticky sessions (e.g. because you are using clustered Tomcats, mirgatable sessions, or you have a stateless web service), it might be a good idea to leave them enabled the the following reasons:

1. Keeping defaults requires less configuration
2. Sticky sessions can make clustered-session replication delays less problematic (e.g. you can use asynchronous session-replication since user requests will almost always go to the same node)

Note that sessions are never sticky if your Tomcat nodes do not have any `jvmRoute` defined in the `<Engine>` component. So you can effectively disable session stickiness by removing your `jvmRoute1`s in your `conf/server.xml` files and no other re-configuration is necessary.

Comment: Thanks a lot christopher , This explanation help me so much  to find my solution .